# How to sort the list of dictionary with repect to time

Tags: python

I have dictionary which is below

```
{
    "id": "98992",
    "data": [
        {
            "app": "Market",
            "hash": "ajlfdfd",
            "nTime": "2021-02-24 16:03:29.149638"
        },
        {
            "app": "Market",
            "hash": "dfds560",
            "nTime": "2021-02-25 05:10:09.828576"
        },
        {
            "app": "Market",
            "hash": "dfdsfds73",
            "nTime": "2021-02-23 15:52:51.954543"
        }
       
    ]
}
```

You can see second is dictionary has to come, Latest has to come first

My expect out is same dictionary with Latest time at top

My psedo code is below

```
def test(mydict):
    for key in sorted(mydict):
       return (nTime, mydict['nTime'])
```

NB: I don't want to use Pandas

Comment: The `sorted` function in python allows to sort something according to a values for examples `sorted(mydict['data'], key=lambda d: d['nTime'])` will sorted mydict['data'] according to the `'nTime'` value. Also you can use the [datetime.date.fromtimestamp](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.fromtimestamp) to convert your date string into a python object that be compared.

Comment: "*NB: I don't want to use Pandas*" Can you expand on the reason for this seemingly arbitrary requirement...? I'm not sure you'd *have* to per se, but what if it's the easiest/fastest/most reliable method?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I sort a list of dictionaries by a value of the dictionary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72899/how-do-i-sort-a-list-of-dictionaries-by-a-value-of-the-dictionary)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your data is stored in variable called `data` you can use this:

```
data['data'] = sorted(data['data'], key=lambda x: x['nTime'], reverse=True)
```